# Set Current Category to Active in category.php

Tags: categories

Inside the category.php file I have a custom navbar which is...

```
<ul class = "nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li><a href="http://example.com/blog/" title="View all posts">All Categories</a></li>
                <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&title_li='); ?>
            </ul>
```

I would like the li for the current category to have class = "active". How can I code this?

Thank you

Comment: The current category link has already a special class: `current-cat`. Why don’t you just use that?

Comment: as I am using bootstrap framework which uses active not current.

Comment: open bootstrap, look at class 'active' and copy it naming if 'current'. Really, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the output on `wp_list_categories`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', function( $html ) {
    return str_replace( ' current-cat', ' active', $html );
});
```

If you are stuck with an outdated PHP version … find a better web hosting. In the mean time, you can try this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'replace_current_cat_css_class' );

function replace_current_cat_css_class( $html ) {
    return str_replace( ' current-cat', ' active', $html );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but where do I put this code??

Comment: In your theme’s `functions.php`.

Comment: I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/a8346489/public_html/wp-content/themes/bootstrap/functions.php on line 9

Comment: @ijames55 Your PHP version is [very old and insecure](http://www.cvedetails.com/version/106044/PHP-PHP-5.2.17.html). Please do yourself a favor and run an upgrade immediately. My script will work then.

Comment: Wow, didn't realise how old it was, I guess free web hosting is free for a reason... Is there any way to get round this?

Comment: @ijames55 See my updated answer. :)

Comment: Hahaha works perfectly, thank you so much :) will bookmark for when I can afford some better hosting ;) will the version for old PHP still be compatible with newer versions of PHP??

Comment: Yes, almost every code written for PHP 5.2 will run on newer versions. You should set up a local test installation to be sure. Something like [this](http://wpkrauts.com/2014/wordpress-in-a-nutshell-wt-nmp/).